# What replaced $this->html( 'headelement' ); in mediawiki skins?

Tags: php, mediawiki, deprecated, skin

I have a mediawiki skin I set up some years ago. It is a simple fixed-width skin. I recently updated mediawiki, and now the skin does not work. I get the error below, which I understand -- that function is deprecated. What I have **not** been able to find is what replaced this deprecated call.

```
Deprecated: Use of QuickTemplate::(get/html/text/haveData) with parameter `headelement` was deprecated in MediaWiki 1.39. [Called from QuickTemplate::html in /home/kaloscomics/wiki.kaloscomics.com/includes/skins/QuickTemplate.php at line 168] in /home/kaloscomics/wiki.kaloscomics.com/includes/debug/MWDebug.php on line 381
```

The code which generates that error is:

```
    public function execute() {
        global $wgSitename;

        $this->data['pageLanguage'] = $this->getSkin()->getTitle()->getPageViewLanguage()->getHtmlCode();

        $this->html( 'headelement' );
```

I have looked at other skins for similar code. I have searched for every combination of "headelement" "mediawiki" and "deprecated" I can think of. I have been searching for days for a clue to this. I have not found a single reference anywhere on what to replace that call with.

I would really rather not completely rebuild the skin from scratch. Is that what I am faced with?

Comment: See https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T306942.  To fix add skin option bodyOnly: true to skin.json and remove any echo statements that echo bottomscripts, headelement or getTrail.

Comment: Thank you. I have done that, and it eliminated the errors, but now the skin does not have the header section, the footer section, the tools... so my question remains: what replaced the deprecated call?

Comment: On further consideration, I think I will rebuild the theme. At this point, I think that will be simpler. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 0):

On further consideration, I think I will rebuild the theme. At this point, I think that will be simpler. Thank you, though.